# Modify prop in list of components generated in a loop

Tags: reactjs

I have a checkbox component that has a `disabled` property.  My goal is:

1. When 3 checkboxes are selected set the `disabled` property to true in all checkboxes that are not selected.
2. Each time a checkbox is selected show an updated count of remaining selection allowed.

For goal 1 I am not sure what the right way to do this is.  Do I need to create an array of refs?

For goal 2 I have added this code:

```
{3 - Object.keys(selected).length + " domains remaining"}
```

But when `selected` is updated the render does not get the updated value.

My code with comment where I want to disable/enable all is on codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-bush-119ef?file=/src/App.js

Also pasted here below:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App(props) {
  const [enableSelection, setEnableSelection] = useState(true);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});

  let domains = [
    "example1.com",
    "example2.com",
    "example3.com",
    "example4.com",
    "example5.com",
    "example6.com",
    "example7.com",
    "example8.com",
    "example9.com",
    "example10.com",
    "example11.com",
    "example12.com",
    "example13.com",
    "example14.com",
    "example15.com",
    "example16.com"
  ];

  function handleChange(index, event) {
    console.log(index);
    console.log(event.target.name);
    console.log(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target.checked);

    if (event.target.checked === true) {
      setSelected((prev) => {
        prev[index] = event.target.value;
        return prev;
      });
    } else {
      setSelected((prev) => {
        delete prev[index];
        return prev;
      });
    }

    if (Object.keys(selected).length >= 3) {
      //disable all other input
    } else {
      //make sure all other enabled
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="">
        <SubHead
          text={3 - Object.keys(selected).length + " domains remaining"}
        />
        {domains.map((domain, i) => (
          <div key={i} className="odd:bg-gray-200">
            <CheckBox
              disabled={false}
              label={domain}
              name={"checkbox_" + i}
              value={domain}
              onChange={(index, e) => handleChange(i, e)}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function CheckBox({
  disabled,
  key,
  label,
  selected,
  name,
  value,
  onChange: parentChange
}) {
  const [selectedState, setSelectedState] = useState(selected ?? false);

  function handleChange(event) {
    setSelectedState(!selectedState);
    parentChange(key, event);
  }

  return (
    <label key={key} className="inline-flex items-center mt-3">
      <input
        id={name}
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="checkbox"
        className="form-checkbox h-5 w-5 text-gray-600"
        disabled={disabled}
        checked={selected}
      />
      <span
        className={
          "ml-2 " +
          (selectedState ? "font-semibold " : "") +
          (disabled ? "text-gray-400" : "text-gray-700")
        }
      >
        {label}
      </span>
    </label>
  );
}

function SubHead(props) {
  return <h3 className="font-medium text-xl text-center">{props.text}</h3>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you handle the event in two places,
You don't need to handle the state of the checkbox twice, once in the parent and another inside it. I also converted the `selected` to array to make it easier:

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-sun-35lfk?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App(props) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  let domains = [
    "example1.com",
    "example2.com",
    "example3.com",
    "example4.com",
    "example5.com",
    "example6.com",
    "example7.com",
    "example8.com",
    "example9.com",
    "example10.com",
    "example11.com",
    "example12.com",
    "example13.com",
    "example14.com",
    "example15.com",
    "example16.com"
  ];

  function handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.name);
    console.log(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target.checked);

    if (event.target.checked) {
      setSelected((prev) => [...prev, event.target.name]);
    } else {
      setSelected((prev) => prev.filter((name) => name !== event.target.name));
    }

    if (Object.keys(selected).length >= 3) {
      //disable all other input
    } else {
      //make sure all other enabled
    }
  }

  const remaining = 3 - Object.keys(selected).length;

  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="">
        <SubHead text={remaining + " domains remaining"} />
        {domains.map((domain) => {
          const checked = selected.indexOf("checkbox_" + domain) > -1;
          return (
            <div key={domain} className="odd:bg-gray-200">
              <CheckBox
                checked={checked}
                disabled={!checked && remaining === 0}
                label={domain}
                name={"checkbox_" + domain}
                value={domain}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function CheckBox({
  checked,
  disabled,
  key,
  label,
  selected,
  name,
  value,
  onChange: parentChange
}) {
  return (
    <label key={key} className="inline-flex items-center mt-3">
      <input
        id={name}
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onChange={parentChange}
        type="checkbox"
        className="form-checkbox h-5 w-5 text-gray-600"
        disabled={disabled}
        checked={selected}
      />
      <span
        className={
          "ml-2 " +
          (checked ? "font-semibold " : "") +
          (disabled ? "text-gray-400" : "text-gray-700")
        }
      >
        {label}
      </span>
    </label>
  );
}

function SubHead(props) {
  return <h3 className="font-medium text-xl text-center">{props.text}</h3>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and providing a working solution. This works in code sandbox but in my project I get an error about needing to use `event.persist()`.  I had to use in chiuld component: `onChange={(e) => {  e.persist();  parentChange(e);  }}`